# Staining a tabletop

Tags: repainting

How can I 'regellify" dried stain on a table top? I don't know the name of the stain, and I would like to re liquefy whats on the table to, and restain it more lightly with the same stain.

Comment: With an oil based stain some times mineral spirits or thinner can be used to lighten a stain color if it has not set long.  I have never tried to lighten a water based stain maybe hot water or steam? But probably sanding.

Answer (score 1):

Give a few of the compounds out there a try, get a quart can of each- lacquer thinner, MEK, Toluol. There more out there that may cut the dried stain to lighten it up. To find more, just look on the shelves of a well stocked hardware or better yet, paint store and look for anything that says "highly volatile", "do not use in enclosed spaces" "prolong use will kill all your brain cells", things of that nature. Try a small spot (or maybe large spot) with a wet rag soaked with any of the above mentioned, brain cell killing solvents. If there is stain coming off on the rag, you are on the right track. I have used these with success and have only managed to drool uncontrollably on occasion. I have a preference for lacquer thinner. Kidding about the drool, but do watch how you use that stuff....

Comment: Your brain isn't the only cells to be careful of.  Wear rubber gloves when you use these solvents as they will defat (leach the oils out of) you skin (not in a good way).  The vapors also aren't great for your lungs, so work with good ventilation.